# Perl: iterating over lines in a file

Tags: perl

```
print "enter file name\n";
$infile = <>;
open IN, "$infile";
$string1 = $line; #store first line of file as $string1
while($line = <IN>){
  $string2 = string1 + $line;
  print "$string2\n";
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that prompts the user to enter the name of a file, opens the file, stores the first line of the file as `$string1`. Then it iterates over the next lines in the file and adds `$string1` to each line and prints out the output.

So if I had a file that contains

```
10
5
6
7
```

`$string1` should be 10. And the output should be:

```
15
16
17
```

My current program seems to only print the contents of my file instead of adding the first line to each of the other lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$line` is empty when you try to give `$string1`.

It can be something like:

```
print "enter file name\n";
$infile = <>;
open IN, "$infile";
$string1 = <IN>; #store first line of file as $string1
chomp($string1);
while($line = <IN>){
  chomp($line);
  $string2 = $line+$string1;
  print( $string2 . "\n");
}
```

The `chomp()` is in order to remove the line breaks from the strings.